# How do you access related data from a pivot model in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel, model, pivot, laravel-5.5

So I have the following relational structure:

`User` - `UserTask` - `Task`

My pivot model (`UserTask`) needs to access a property from the `Task` model.

So I have an accessor function in my `UserTask` model in which I need to access the `Task->document_upload_required` property.

Any one know how I can access this?

Note:

I cannot set the accessor in the parent model because I need to use the Media functions set on the pivot model.

Here is how I've defined the relationships:

Task:

```
class Task extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_task')->using('App\Models\UserTask')->withPivot('completed');
    }


}
```

UserTask:

```
class UserTask extends Pivot implements HasMedia
{
    use HasMediaTrait;

    public function getCompletedAttribute()
    {
        return "Need to access parent attribute here";
    }

}
```

User:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable, Billable;

    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Task::class);
    }

}
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is my pivot (`UserTask`) table that I am trying to fetch data from:

[image]

Here is the function in my pivot model:

```
public function isComplete() {

        if($this->task->document_upload_required) {
            return $this->getMedia()->isEmpty() && $this->completed;
        } else {
            return $this->completed;
        }
    }


    public function getCompletedAttribute()
    {
        return $this->isComplete();
    }
```

Here is how I make the call to join the models:

```
 $sections = $this->model->with(['subsections.tasks.users' => function($q){
            $q->where('users.id', '=', Auth::id());
        }])->where('parent', NULL)->doesntHave('assessments')->sorted()->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the relationship first and then access its property, like this:

```
public function task()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Task::class);
}
public function getCompletedAttribute()
{
    return $this->task->completed;
}
```

EDIT:

```
$collection = $this->model->with(['subsections.tasks.users' => function($q){
    $q->where('users.id', '=', Auth::id());
}])->where('parent', NULL)->doesntHave('assessments')->sorted()->get();

$collection->each(function($subsection) {
    $subsection->tasks->each(function($task) {
        $task->users->each(function($user) {
            dump($user->pivot->completed);
        });
    });
});
dd();
```

Comment: Also how do I access the actual pivot table columns from the pivot model itself?

Comment: to access pivot data from pivot model you can use `withPivot` function on relationships inside the model, for the first comment im not sure what you mean

Comment: If I have a column on the pivot model called `completed` and I want to access that column from the pivot model itself it throws an error: "Undefined property: App\\Models\\UserTask::$completed"

Comment: `$this->completed` just doesn't work... but if I access one of the keys `$this->user_id` it works fine.

Comment: I can't help you like this, show us your tables, I need to see which columns u have and where

Comment: See my update for the pivot table. Thats the only one you need to see as I'm trying to fetch data from there

Comment: Are you trying to access `pivot model` from user or task model?

Comment: No... I have a function in my pivot model itself and I am trying to access the `completed` attribute from the pivot model itself... not from another model.

Comment: remove `getCompletedAttribute` function on your `UserTask` model

Comment: But I need that as it accesses the function. See edit

Comment: Show me the code where you get `UserTask` model, I wanna see how you access that model, from user? from task? or directly

Comment: Then you can see the above `Task` model where I call the `UserTask` pivot model

Comment: Subsections? Whats that?

Comment: That's a parent model... but that not related anyway. the problem is I can't access a specific property in my `UserTask` model but I can access other properties.

Comment: Because you are not calling `withPivot` on the correct relationship, and Im trying to figure out in which model in the chain you are not calling it...

Comment: `withPivot` is called on the `Task` model which is fine. The relational structure is fine its just something to do with accessing additional pivot properties.

Comment: if the relational structure was not correct then it would not return the pivot model correctly.

Comment: It returns the model correctly, but the thing is you are not including `pivot attribute completed` from one of the relationships, and if you are not willing to cooperate, I can't help you

Comment: I am including it in my Task model like I previously explained: `return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_task')->using('App\Models\UserTask')->withPivot('completed');`

Comment: How am I not willing to cooperate?

Comment: You gotta access the completed from within user model or retrieve `pivot model` directly from database and work on it, check my updated answer

Comment: That returns nothing. I need to access it from my pivot model not from the user model because I am defining an accessor so I can manipulate the property before I send it back.

Comment: `$userTask = UserTask::find(1); $userTask->completed;`

Comment: That's not what I'm doing though. I am querying all of the related data so I can't create an object manually. it's all relational nested data.